# Wordpress comments have footer tag

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, comments

I am developing at wordpress theme, and ran into a problem.
my comments are showing up with the same background image as my footer have, and i can't find the footer tag in the comments.php in my theme, so my question is there any other palce i should look ? 
btw. the footer tag is visable in the source when showing the website

```
<footer class="comment-meta">
```

I have also tried to search across all theme files and searching for "footer" and only the

```
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

showed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found the answer:**
The file i was looking for is called "comment-template.php" and i located in "wp-includes/" and on line 1940 i found this: `<footer class="comment-meta">`

Answer (score 0):

check the template where you comment is form is embedded.the footer file is not included in comment template.

```
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

is used to call the footer.php in template. So if your comment form is embedded in single file try to check single.php there you can find both the footer.php and comment template.

```
<footer class="comment-meta">
```

This will found in your footer.php file

Comment: the <footer class="comment-meta"> is not found, not in the footer.php, not in single.php or in any other file in my theme.

The comment template file is the one called comments.php in my theme folder right?